# Best brand of premium gas?

Tags: engine, fuel-system

I just bought a car with a turbo engine that requires 91 premium gas.  Out of the major gasoline companies like Shell, Chevron, BP, etc., is there one in particular <strike>that is better than the others</strike> that has been consistently documented to be superior to the others for engine life and performance?  I live in Chicago, within the city, if that matters.

Answer (score 3):

There is no brand that is superior to the others. Most gas stations in an area get their fuel from the same refinery. Larger companies may have slightly different specs, but there is not a single brand of 91 octane that's better than the others.

However, there is a difference between gasoline with ethanol and gasoline without it. Ethanol free gas has a little better performance. This is because gasoline produces more energy than ethanol when it burns.

Comment: Yes, I have read that most gas stations in an area get all their fuel from the same supplier, but I understand that the difference is in the additives blended into the fuel.  I was hoping for some expert opinion or credible citations as to which is better.  Can you provide?  Thanks!

Comment: I had a co-worker who used to do chemistry in the petroleum industry, and he was adamant that all the brands came "out of the same tank at the refinery".  I said that I had heard (from the Chevron marketing) that they included different additives, but he would just shake his head and say they were all the same.